# How to deploy a Spring Boot REST API service on Azure App Service and use it via secure HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a spring boot REST API service. I need to deploy that service to Azure App Service. Any relatively cheap service where I can host those API and access them via HTTPS. Since using a VM I would have to purchase an additional SSL certificate. What are my other alternatives to deploy secure REST Service?

Comment: If you'd like to deploy your app to azure, I think using app service plan is the most convenient way to enable ssl as Microsoft  has provided the service plan now. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZCjV.png

Comment: What are my alternatives for the database part Is it possible to use containers using the App Service and bundle them together?

Comment: Hmmm, I can just tell you that I usually use cosmosdb or azure sql database, they all provided by azure so I don't have to consider how to deploy database.

Answer (score 0):

In your case here, I suggest to use app service plan to enable SSL as Microsoft has provided the service plan now. You only need to choose a suitable pricing tiers to obtain that feature.

[image]